# create input text with loop js

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how could I create many `<input type=text />` tags with a loop in JS.

I need that loop to be linked to a first input (`type=number`), which tell to the loops how many input text to create.

```js
function getP () {
  var nbP = Number(document.getElementById("nombreP").value);

  for (var i = 0; i < nbP; i++) {
      var newForm = document.createElement("input[type=text]");
          newForm.id = "form"+i
      document.body.appendChild(newForm);
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="get">
    <input type="number" name="nombrePlat" id="nombreP">
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" id="ok" onclick="getP()">
</form>
```

Comment: No need to say sorry! Everyone has to learn at one point. What exactly do you want to do with these inputs, should they be in one form or do you want multiple forms?

Comment: – AFAIK you can not create element using bracket notation ike this, you probably need to create `input`in the first place and then set `type` attribute,
– More important you can not add inputs with a `submit` button, you need another button or somethin like that,
– Your loop condition shoul probably be `<=` rather than `<` (if you use `<` and the value is 5, you got only 4 inputs),
But in general your are following a good path, just keep trying.

Comment: These inputs would stock 2-3 words that will be use next to create an url. Exemple : http://xxxx.tk:port/NumberOfInput=<nbP>&plat0=<input text 1>&plat1=<input text 2>&plat2=input text3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct answer to your question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getP() {
    var nbP = +document.getElementById("nombreP").value;
    var inputContainer = document.getElementById("inutContainer");

    for (var i = 0; i < nbP; i++) {
        var newForm = document.createElement("input");
        newForm.setAttribute("type", "text");
        newForm.setAttribute("id", "form"+i);
        inputContainer.appendChild(newForm);
        inputContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
</script>
<form>
    <input type="number" name="nombrePlat" id="nombreP">
    <input type="button" value="Envoyer" id="ok" onclick="getP()">
    <div id="inutContainer">
</div>
</form>
```

**BUT**: this is good question to learn about Javascript and HTML, but bad to create powerfull UI. To implement modern UI in JS/HTML i am strongly recommend to learn more abou next technologies:

https://reactjs.org/ or https://angular.io/ or https://vuejs.org/

Comment: Thanks ! But I suppose I need to know well JS before start learning React (for example) ?

Comment: sure, that why i wrote that it's good question to learn, but bad example to prod implementation =)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps:

```js
document.querySelector('#ok').addEventListener('click', getP)

function getP(event) {
  let inputsQtt = document.querySelector('input[type=number]').value
  for (let i = 0; i < inputsQtt; i++) {
    let input = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(input);
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="get">
  <input type="number" name="nombrePlat" id="nombreP">
  <input type="button" value="Envoyer" id="ok">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code
First: syntax error, you are missing 1 curly bracket } to close function.

And second and more important as you click on button it causes to submit form and refreshes the page.To solve this you just need to change type of button from submit to button.

And also you can not use "input[type=text]" to create element.You can just create an element with following code

```
function getP () {
    var nbP = Number(document.getElementById("nombreP").value);
    for (var i = 0; i < nbP; i++) {
        var newForm = document.createElement("input");
        newForm.id = "form"+i;
        newForm.setAttribute("type","text");
        document.body.appendChild(newForm);      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach, that involves adding a wrapper container within your form.

```js
function updateForm() {

  var parent = document.getElementById('inputs'),
      count = document.getElementById('inputCount').value || 0;
  
  parent.innerHTML = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    parent.innerHTML += `<input placeholder="text input ${i+1}" name="form${i+1}" id="form${i+1}" /><br>`;
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<form method="get" name="inputForm">
    <input min="0" type="number" name="inputCount" id="inputCount">
  
    <div id="inputs">
       <!-- container for dynamic inputs -->
    </div>

</form>

<!-- Notice inputs can also be associated to form with `form` attribute -->
<input form="inputForm" type="submit" value="Make" id="ok" onclick="updateForm()">
```